# Need to Load .aspx page asynchronously through Master page hyperlink event using update panel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

---

I need to load pages asynchronously using asp.net C#.
I have a master with Two(2) hyperlink controls and One(1) ContentPlaceHolder.
I do not need page refresh or mute the page refresh to load page Async by clicking the hypelink control given on master page.
Code for Main.Master page, Home.aspx page and the products.aspx is given below.

### Main.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="AsyncPageLoadFromMasterLink.Main" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <div id="navbar">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHome" NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx" runat="server">Home</asp:HyperLink>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkProducts" NavigateUrl="~/products.aspx" runat="server">Products</asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
                <div id="main">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

### home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="AsyncPageLoadFromMasterLink.home" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1>This is Home Page</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

### products.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="products.aspx.cs" Inherits="AsyncPageLoadFromMasterLink.products" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1>This is Products page</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

Bundle of Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you need to add the hyperlinks to the update panel and bind the hyperlink's `OnClick()` event to the update panel's trigger.

Comment: it is just blueprint, I have developed a management system which has a navigation-bar, so I need to navigate asynchronously between .aspx page from my site's top navigation-bar.
when I do this, the Visual Studio **intellisense** alert me with green line that you can not use any **<DIV>** tag inside update-panel.
Hope you will better understand my purpose of doing that.

Comment: I understand now what you are asking. Thanks for the clarification. You might be able to do something like this using a a script manager. I can speak about that as I have no experience doing what you are asking in web forms.